# What's the limit of $\prod_1^\infty \left(1-\frac{1}{2^n}\right)=(1-1/2)(1-1/4)(1-1/8)...$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, infinite-product

I know that

$$\prod_1^\infty \left(1-\frac{1}{2^n}\right)$$

converges to a positive number because the series $\sum 2^{-n}$ is convergent.  Do we know the limit?  If so, how?

**Aside:**  I am interested in this product because it describes asymptotically the fraction of $n\times n$ matrices with entries in $\mathbb{F}_2$ that are nonsingular.

Comment: You are using $n$ as a bound variable in the sum and product. So what is it doing as a matrix dimension?

Comment: This is $\phi(1/2)$, one of [Euler's functions](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerFunction.html).

Comment: @JohnBentin as mentioned in the OP, the claim about matrices is asymptotic, so it is a bound variable (in the scope of the same quantifier) in that context too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a tautology but, your product is a [$q$-Pochhammer symbol](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PochhammerSymbol.html)  $(\frac{1}{2}; \frac{1}{2})_\infty$. One connection to Jacobi-Theta functions is:

$$\left(\frac{1}{2}; \frac{1}{2}\right)_\infty=\frac{2^{1/24}}{\sqrt{3}}\vartheta_2\left(\frac{1}{6}\pi,\frac{1}{2^{1/6}}\right)$$

where $\vartheta_n$ is the Jacobi theta function.

Comment: @O.L.: good point. I was mostly just thinking of gamma functions. I've adjusted the answer.

Answer (score 16):

Let $$P = \prod_{n\ge 1} \left(1 - \frac{1}{2^n} \right).$$ Introduce
$$S = \log P = \sum_{n\ge 1} \log\left(1 - \frac{1}{2^n} \right).$$

Now recall the harmonic sum identity for Mellin transforms:
$$\mathfrak{M}\left(\sum_{k\ge 1} \lambda_k g(\mu_k x);s\right) =
\left(\sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{\lambda_k}{\mu_k^s} \right) g^*(s)$$
where $g^*(s)$ is the Mellin transform of $g(x).$

Introducing $$S(x)= \sum_{n\ge 1} \log\left(1 - \frac{1}{2^{nx}} \right)$$
so that $S=S(1)$ we see that $S(x)$ is harmonic with parameters
$$\lambda_k = 1, \quad \mu_k = k
\quad\text{and}\quad g(x) =  \log\left(1 - \frac{1}{2^x} \right)$$
and may be evaluated (approximated) by inverting its Mellin transform.

Now $$\mathfrak{M}\left(\log\left(1 - \frac{1}{2^x} \right);s\right) =
\int_0^\infty \log\left(1 - \frac{1}{2^x} \right) x^{s-1} dx =
- \int_0^\infty \sum_{q\ge 1} \frac{2^{-qx}}{q}  x^{s-1} dx.$$
This is
$$-\frac{\Gamma(s)}{(\log 2)^s} \sum_{q\ge 1} \frac{1}{q} \frac{1}{q^s} =
-\frac{\Gamma(s)}{(\log 2)^s} \zeta(s+1).$$
It follows that the Mellin transform of $S(x)$ is
$$Q(s) = \mathfrak{M}(S(x); s) = -\frac{1}{(\log 2)^s}\Gamma(s)\zeta(s)\zeta(s+1).$$
Now perform Mellin inversion with the inversion integral being
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{3/2-i\infty}^{3/2+i\infty} Q(s)/x^s ds$$
and shifting the integral to the left for an expansion about zero. There are only three singularities to consider because the trivial zeros of the two zeta function terms cancel the poles of the gamma function.

We have
$$\operatorname{Res}(Q(s)/x^s; s=1) =
-1/6\,{\frac {{\pi }^{2}}{\log 2\times  x}},$$
$$\operatorname{Res}(Q(s)/x^s; s=0) =
1/2\,\log  \left( 2\,\pi  \right) -1/2\,\log  \log 2
-1/2\,\log x$$
and
$$\operatorname{Res}(Q(s)/x^s; s=-1) =
1/24\,\log 2 \times x.$$
Putting $x=1$ we obtain that
$$S(1) = S \approx -1/6\,{\frac {{\pi }^{2}}{\log 2}}
+ 1/2\,\log  \left( 2\,\pi  \right) -1/2\,\log  \log 2 + 1/24\,\log 2.$$
This approximation is excellent (good to $24$ digits) but not quite exact. E.g. setting $x=1/2$ which is closer to zero we get $50$ good digits, setting $x=1/5$ we get $123$ good digits and so on.

The conclusion is that
$$ P \approx e^{-\pi^2/6/\log 2} \times \sqrt{2\pi} \times
 \frac{2^{1/24}}{\sqrt{\log 2}}
\approx 0.2887880950866024212788997.$$

**Adddendum, July 2022.** We can actually do a somewhat better and
compute a  functional equation for $S(x).$ This requires an evaluation of the  remainder, which is

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{-3/2-i\infty}^{-3/2+i\infty}
Q(s)/x^s \; ds.$$

Substitute $s = - t$ in this integral to get
(we get one minus from $Q(s)$, another from the differential, and a
third reversing the direction of the line)

$$-\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{3/2-i\infty}^{3/2+i\infty}
(\log 2)^t
\Gamma(-t) \zeta(-t) \zeta(1-t)
x^{t} dt$$

In view of  the desired functional equation we  now use the functional
equation  of the Riemann  zeta function  on $Q(s)$  to prove  that the
integrand of the last integral is in fact a scaled version of $Q(t).$

Start with the functional equation
$$\zeta(1-s) = \frac{2}{2^s\pi^s}
\cos\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right) \Gamma(s) \zeta(s)$$
and substitute this into $Q(s)$ to obtain

$$Q(s) =
- \frac{1}{(\log 2)^s}
\frac{\zeta(1-s) 2^s \pi^s}{2\cos\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)}
\zeta(s+1).$$

Apply the functional equation again (this time to $\zeta(s+1)$) to get

$$- \frac{1}{(\log 2)^s}
\frac{\zeta(1-s) 2^s \pi^s}{2\cos\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)}
2^{s+1} \pi^s
\cos\left(-\frac{\pi s}{2}\right) \Gamma(-s) \zeta(-s).$$

This is

$$Q(s) =
- 2^{2s} \pi^{2s}  \frac{1}{(\log 2)^s}
\Gamma(-s) \zeta(-s) \zeta(1-s).$$

We thus have for the remainder integral (there was a minus in front and
the multiple of $Q(t)$ brings another one)

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{3/2-i\infty}^{3/2+i\infty}
(\log 2)^t
\frac{Q(t)}{2^{2t} \pi^{2t}} (\log 2)^t
x^{t} dt
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{3/2-i\infty}^{3/2+i\infty}
Q(t) \left(\frac{4\pi^2}{x(\log 2)^2}\right)^{-t} \; dt.$$

Together with the residues we have established the following functional
equation

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\begin{gather}
S(x) = - \frac{1}{6} \frac{\pi^2}{\log 2 \times x}
+ \frac{1}{2} \log(2\pi/\log 2/ x)
+ \frac{1}{24} \log 2 \times x
\\ + S \left(\frac{4\pi^2}{x(\log 2)^2}\right)
\end{gather}.}$$

The fixed point at $x=2\pi/\log 2$ of the recursion does not produce a
value here, but we  get by way of confirming the computation that

$$0 = -\frac{1}{6} \frac{\pi^2}{2\pi}
+ \frac{1}{24} 2\pi.$$

Comment: Just curious, what branch of mathematics would this be considered? Real analysis? I'm fascinated by it, but have yet to learn a majority of the concepts used here.

Comment: @infinitylord I'd say real + complex analysis.

Comment: I have to leave a comment for hystorical purposes: this technique provides unbelievably good approximations for $\prod_{n\geq 0}\left(1\pm K^n\right)$, i.e. for q-Pochhammer symbols. Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4487684/evaluation-of-prod-limits-n-0-inftyne-n1/4488083#4488083

Comment: Can the method be used to approximate the limit in this question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4818277/1231520  as a function of $t$ ? or $$\prod_{i=1}^{\infty} (1- 2^{-i}t ).$$