# How to calculate $\prod _{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^n-1}{2^n}$?

Tags: probability, limits, infinite-product, lotteries

> Suppose we have a kind of lottery as follow:
>
> $1.$ You have a $\frac{1}{2}$ possibility of getting a prize on the first try.
> $2.$ You have a $\frac{1}{4}$ possibility of getting a prize on the second try.
> $\quad\vdots$
> $n.$ The probability is $\frac{1}{2^{n}}$ on the $n$th try.
> $\quad\vdots$
>
> What is the probability of getting at least one prize?

I know that it is

$$p = 1- \prod _{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^n-1}{2^n},$$

But how to calculate it? I don't know. I want to find the answer.

Thanks.

Comment: There is no known closed-form of that product, see [Euler's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_function), for instance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the limit of $\prod_1^\infty \left(1-\frac{1}{2^n}\right)=(1-1/2)(1-1/4)(1-1/8)...$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/491948/whats-the-limit-of-prod-1-infty-left1-frac12n-right-1-1-21-1-4)

Answer (score 0):

We have- $$P=\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \Biggr(\frac{2^n-1}{2^n}\Biggr)=\lim_{N\to \infty}\prod_{k=1}^{N} \Biggr(1-\frac{1}{2^k}\Biggr)=\lim_{N\to \infty} (1/2)^N\prod_{k=1}^{N} \frac{\Biggr(1-\frac{1}{2^k}\Biggr)}{(1-\frac{1}{2})^N}$$
$$=\lim_{N\to\infty}(1/2)^N \times\lim_{N\to\infty}\prod_k\Biggr(\sum_{r=0}^{k-1}(\frac{1}{2})^r \Biggr)$$

Now,let $$L=\lim_{N\to\infty}\prod_k\Biggr(\sum_{r=0}^{k-1}(\frac{1}{2})^r \Biggr)=\lim\prod_k (1+u_k)$$ where $u_k=\Biggr(\sum_{r=0}^{k-1}(\frac{1}{2})^r -1\Biggr)$. Here $\{u_k\} $ is convergent as $k\to \infty$. So $L$ is a finite limit i.e. $L\in \Bbb R$.
Therefore, $$P=\lim_N (½)^N ×L=0.$$

This is my approach, but I'm confused that in the following P, each term is $>0$. So how the product can be zero! Please anyone spot any mistake ,please let me know.  Thank you.